# Sitecore 9.0.2 Windows Authentication when access the URL

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

We want windows authentication for sitecore 9 update 2 version. We have applied windows authentication in iis but not working, Same settings working for plain asp.net or html site in iis. is any body know how to enable windows authentication in sitecore 9 update 2? We want something like when you hit the url it should popup for credentials and then everything goes as per sitecore.

Like this way.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/323176/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

We have tested same thing with Sitecore 8 and it was working fine but Sitecore 9 it is not working.

We find alternate solution like site defination tag add two attributes things requiredlogin="true" and loginpage="/sitecore/login"